# apt-get can't find postfix installation candidate on raspberry pi 3 (stretch)

Tags: raspberry-pi, apt-get, debian-stretch

I'm trying to install the MTA postfix on my raspberry pi 3 (stretch)

What I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

-> updates without error

```
sudo apt-get install postfix libsasl2-modules bsd-mailx
```

-> error: can not find installation canidates

My etc/apt/sources.list.d files:

1. ajenti.list
2. nodesource.list
3. raspi.list

in raspi.list:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui staging
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

What else did I try:

- sudo apt-get upgrade to install the newest sources.
- login as pi and as root
- tested that the internet-connection works correctly
- googled for a solution

The pi is running nginx as a reverse proxy and ajenti as a admin-panel

Thanks in advance for constructive feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution myself:

in /etc/apt the sources.list-file (not the directory "sources.list.d") was missing. So I added a new file, named sources.list and put

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
```

in it. apt-get install could find the install canidates then.